# How to create a unit test class

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I inherited a solution with 4 projects: Front-End Project, Business Project, Data Project and a Test Project.

The test project is quite... let's say empty... and now after I changed a few things on some searches methods of the business class I would like to generate some tests to validate the changes i've made.

So my question is: Is there a automatic way to generate a "empty frame test class" to test my actual code? Something like "right click the class you want to test and click generate test class and choose the project where it will be created" maybe?!?

Details:

- I'm using VS 2012 Ultimate
- There's no tests for the class I'm working on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is built in functionality that allows you to create unit test classes. I am not sure if that also works in combination with NUnit though.

Anyway, I never used it. What I do is:

- add a test class to the test project
- decorate the class with the [TestFixture] attribute
- write the first method of what I want to test
- decorate the method with the [Test] attribute
- write the test

and start the [TDD cycle](http://agileinaflash.blogspot.nl/2009/02/red-green-refactor.html).

A typical test class skeleton will look like this

using NUnit.Framework;

```
namespace Tests.Framework
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class SomeClassTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void AMeaningfulTestMethodName()
        {
            // the test
        }
    }
}
```

I also have [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) at my aid so that I can run the test from visual studio straight away.

[image]

Since it's so little effort for me to add a new test fixture to the project, I don't see the need of adding it via templates. The most annoying part of templates is that they overgenerate. Templates will generate `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]` fixtures which I don't always need. I like to keep my classes as clean as possible. But it's a matter of taste.

Here are some links that you might find helpful if you want to:

- save your own [predefined test class template](http://tsells.wordpress.com/2010/02/07/how-to-create-nunit-test-class-for-visual-studio/)
- want to use the [built in functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465183.aspx) of visual studio
- follow a [msdn walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410597%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) regarding the topic